# Debugging incomplete runs of a dag in mwaa

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, mwaa

we deployed MWAA using [mwaa_enviroment](https://github.com/aws-ia/terraform-aws-mwaa/blob/main/examples/basic/dags/hello_world_dag.py) terraform resource.  I added example [dag](https://github.com/aws-ia/terraform-aws-mwaa/blob/main/examples/basic/dags/hello_world_dag.py) but none of the runs complete.  What do I need to debug what is happening?

First image is where say_hello task stays in up_for_retry status. Second image is when I click log from the say_hello task.

Our MWAA environment's role already has this in it's policy.

```
  statement {
    actions = [
      "logs:*",
    ]
    resources = ["arn:aws:logs:${var.region}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:log-group:airflow-axiom_mwaa-*:*"]
  }
```

[image: up_for_retry]

[image: log message]

Comment: Two things to try. `1)` Allow action `logs:DescribeLogGroups` for resource `*`. `2)` Remove extra `:*` at the end of the resource ARN (maybe this is a bug/syntax error).

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not help.